# Simplify and find the value of $\sec40°$ $·$ $\sec80°$ $·$ $\sec160°$

Tags: trigonometry

I have found it in the calculator in said
$\sec(40°)·\sec(80°)·\sec(160°) = -8.$

But how can I simplify the term to find the solution that is -8?

How can I apply basic angles, say, $0°, 30°, 45°, 60°,$ or $90°$ for this?

(Edit) I finally got it everyone.

Some said I should use

$\cos(40°) + \cos(80°) = \cos(20°)$,

and $2\cos(A)\cos(B) = \cos(A+B) + \cos(A-B)$.

Turned out like this,

$\cos(40°)\cos(80°) = \frac{1}{2} [\cos(120°) + \cos(-40°)] = -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\cos(40°)$.

Hence,

$\cos(40°)\cos(80°)\cos(160°) = -\frac{\cos(160°)}{4} + \frac{\cos(40°)\cos(160°)}{2}$

$= \frac{\cos(20°)}{4} + \frac{\cos(200°) + \cos(-120°)}{4}$

$= \frac{\cos(20°)}{4} - \frac { \cos(20°)+\frac{1}{2}}{4}$

$= - \frac{1}{8}$

Then I should finally flip the reciprocal to find the $\sec$

Thank you everyone

Comment: try using the formula $2\cos A \cos B = \cos(A+B)  + \cos(A-B)$ repeatedly and correctly.

Comment: Else, you could also multiply and divide the expression with $\csc 40^o$

Comment: $\cos (200)+\cos (40)+\cos (280)=0$

Comment: See https://brainly.in/question/147501

Comment: @Supakorn, Where is the polynomial?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee sec40°sec80°sec160° is the polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$\cos u \cos v=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos (u+v)+\cos (u-v) \right)$$

$$\cos 40+\cos 200+\cos 280=0$$

---

In order to prove the identity above about the sum of the cosines, note that we may instead prove:

$$\cos 40-\cos 20+\cos 80=0$$

---

This is because $\cos (360-x)=\cos x$ and $\cos (180-x)=-\cos x$

---

So we may instead prove that,

$$\cos 40+\cos 80=\cos 20$$

But,

$$\cos a+\cos b=2\cos (\frac{a+b}{2})\cos(\frac{a-b}{2})$$

And we are done.

(This formula comes from letting $u=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and letting $v=\frac{a-b}{2}$ in the first formula given).